# Using translate in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, translate

I have a word with vowels like `apple` and want to replace the vowels with asterisks using `translate`. I am using Python 2.7.

I have created a translate table:

```
import string
table = string.maketrans('*****', 'aeiou')
```

But using it removes the vowels without replacing the vowel with asterisk:

```
>> 'apple'.translate(table, 'aeiou')
'ppl'
```

I already know that I can implement this using other methods like `re`:

```
import re
re.sub('[aeiou]', '*', 'Apple', flags=re.I)
```

But I want to know if there is a way using `translate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you need to give it a proper mapping that allows the `__getitem__` method as per the docstring

```
maps = {'a': '*', 'e': '*', 'o': '*', 'i': '*', 'u': '*'}

table = str.maketrans(maps)

'apple'.translate(table)

'*ppl*'
```

Since you now mention `Python 2.7` solution it would be like this:

```
import string

table = string.maketrans('aeoiu', '*****')

'apple'.translate(table)
'*ppl*'
```

Comment: `Python 2.7` prints out `TypeError: maketrans() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

Comment: I see, my problem was providing vowels inside of `translate()`, tnx.

Answer (score 2):

This could help you:

```
table = string.maketrans('aeiou', '*****')
'apple'.translate(table)
```